# Equivalent of getPane method of a GMap2 object in Google map api version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

In one of my project I am appending a *div* in *google map*'s (version 2) `G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE` using *jquery*.

Here is the code:

```
// map is a GMap2 object
$("#MyCustomDiv").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));
```

How can I achieve a similar functionality in *google map version 3*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the 'floatShadow' pane.

You will need to use a custom overlay. For information on adding overlays to specific panes see here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Initializing

Comment: Yes, I did look into it. But I was looking for a simpler solution :), because in V2 it was very easy to add a custom overlay.